# Weka classifier does not run for large number of instances

Tags: weka, naivebayes

I am using my data to train Weka NaiveBayes classifier. I am running cross validation. When i run it for 5000 instances, it runs just fine but when I increase the number of instances to 100000, it just stays there showing:

> 'Building model on training data'

There is no result and weka stops working on the data after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Please share your code. are you using java api or running through GUI. What is the size of the JVM.

The possible reason could be

The textual output shown in the Explorer is that produced when learning 
the model on all the available data. This is also the model that is saved 
when you export the serialized classifier to disk. The rationale is that 
if you were to put a model into production to predict future instances 
you'd want to use the model built from all the available training data. If 
you are not interested in this model you can turn this off (and save time) 
in the "More options" dialog.

[provided here](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/quot-Building-model-on-training-data-quot-td26329.html)

Answer (score 0):

The java vm has probably ran out of memory. Increase the heap size in RunWeka.ini to get around this or maybe use less data. You can open and keep open the CLI window before starting training so that you can see the error output.